# An example of convergence to Young measures

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, calculus-of-variations, weak-convergence

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\lam}{\lambda}$

I am trying to prove the following claim:

Let $\{u:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R} \mid u \, \, \text{  is differentiable a.e}, u(0)=u(1)=0 \}^{*} $. Consider the functional $I(u)=\int_0^1 ((u')^2-1)^2+u $

For **every** minimizing sequence $u_n$ of $I$, the sequence of derivatives $u_n'$ generates the **[Young measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_measure)** $\nu_x =\frac{1}{2}(\delta_1+\delta_{-1})$

(This is taken [from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_measure#Example)).

So far I have succeeded in proving** this only for a **specific** minimizing sequence, which is a natural one to consider. My proof uses the specific structure of this sequence, so it is not applicable as is to the general case.

**My question then, is how to prove this is true for every minimizing sequence?**

---

(*) Perhaps the right space should be some Sobolev space (and then the boundary condition is in the trace sense).

(**) Here is my proof:

Define $A_1=[0,\frac{1}{2}],A_2=[0,\frac{1}{4}] \cup[\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4}],A_3=[0,\frac{1}{8}]\cup [\frac{2}{8},\frac{3}{8}]\cup [\frac{4}{8},\frac{5}{8}]\cup [\frac{6}{8},\frac{7}{8}]$, and so on for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Define a sequence of ``zig-zag triangle'' functions, such that $|u_n| \le \frac{1}{2^n}$, and

$$ u'_n(x) =
\begin{cases}   
1,  & \text{if $x\in A_n$} \\
-1, & \text{if $x \notin A_n$}
\end{cases} 
$$

Then $(u'_n)^2=1$ a.e so $I(u_n) \le \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \rightarrow 0$.

Let $f:\R \to \R$ be a continuous function satisfying  $\lim_{|\lambda|\to\infty}f(\lambda) =0$. Then

$$ (f \circ u'_n)(x) =
\begin{cases}   
f(1),  & \text{if $u_n'(x) =1$} \\
f(-1), & \text{if $u_n'(x) = -1$}
\end{cases} 
$$

i.e,

$$ (f \circ u'_n)(x) =
\begin{cases}   
f(1),  & \text{if $x\in A_n$} \\
f(-1), & \text{if $x \in [0,1] \setminus A_n$}
\end{cases} 
$$

So, denoting $f \circ u_n' =F_n$, we need to show $F_n$ converges in the weak* topology on $L^\infty([0,1])$ to the function:
$F(x) = \int_{\R} f d\nu_x =\frac{1}{2}(f(1)+f(-1))$.

By definition of weak* convergence in $L^{\infty}=\left( L^1 \right)^*$ this means that for every $g \in L^{1}([0,1])$ :

$$(1) \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 F_n(x)g(x)\,dx= \int_0^1 F(x)g(x)\,dx= \frac{1}{2}(f(1)+f(-1)) \cdot  \int_0^1 g(x)\,dx $$

Now,
$$ \int_0^1 F_n(x)g(x)\,dx= f(1) \int_{A_n} g(x)\,dx + f(-1) \int_{[0,1] \setminus A_n} g(x)\,dx$$

Noting that $[0,1] \setminus A_n = A_n + \frac{1}{2^n}$, we get

$$(2) \int_0^1 F_n(x)g(x) \, dx= f(1) \int_{A_n} g(x) \, dx + f(-1) \int_{A_n + \frac{1}{2^n}} g(x)\,dx$$

So, by $(1),(2)$ it's enough to prove $$ (3) \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} g(x)\,dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{A_n+\frac{1}{2^n}} g(x) \, dx= \frac{1}{2}  \int_0^1 g(x)\,dx $$

We turn to handle the second integral:

First, note that we can extend $g$ to $\R$ by putting $g|_{\R \setminus \left[ 0,1 \right]}=0$.
(Now we think of $g \in L^1(\R)$).

By variables changing: $y=x-\frac{1}{2^n}$ we get:

$$(4) \int_{A_n + \frac{1}{2^n}} g(x)dx = \int_{A_n}g\left(y+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right) \,dy=\int_{A_n} g_{\frac{1}{2^n}}(y)dy $$

where $g_h(y)=g(y+h)$ (This is part of the reason we needed to extend $g$ to all $\R$, so now we do not need to worry about what happens when we ``translate'' outside the limits where the original $g$ is defined).

By the $L^1$-continuity of translation,we know:
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \int_\R |g_h(x)-g(x)| \, dx =0, $$ so in particular:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\R |g_{\frac{1}{2^n}}(x)-g(x)|\,dx = 0, $$

and since $$ \int_\R \left|g_{\frac{1}{2^n}}(x)-g(x)\right|\,dx \ge  \int_{A_n} \left|g(x)_{\frac{1}{2^n}}-g(x)\right|\,dx \ge 0 $$

we get:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} \left|g_{\frac{1}{2^n}}(x)-g(x)\right|\,dx = 0, $$

so

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \int_{A_n} g_{\frac{1}{2^{n}}}(x)-g(x)\,dx \right| = 0, $$

which by $(4)$ is equivalent to:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} | \int_{A_n+\frac{1}{2^{n}}} g(x) -\int_{A_n}g(x)dx \,  | = 0, $$

However, it is also holds that:

$$ \int_{A_n+\frac{1}{2^{n}}} g(x) + \int_{A_n}g(x)dx = \int_0^1 g(x)dx$$

So, after denoting $a_n = \int_{A_n+\frac{1}{2^{n}}} g(x)dx \, , \, b_n =\int_{A_n}g(x)dx, c=\int_0^1 g(x)dx $, we are in the following situation:

$$a_n+b_n=c, \lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n-b_n|=0 $$

This implies: $2a_n=(a_n+b_n)+(a_n-b_n)=c +(a_n-b_n) \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =\frac{c}{2}  $, so actually
$ \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n =\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =\frac{c}{2}  $

In our context, this translates into:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} g(x)\,dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{A_n+\frac{1}{2^{n}}} g(x)\,dx= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 g(x)\,dx $$

Which is exactly $(3)$ we wanted to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to read the lectures notes by Müller which are linked in the Wikipedia article, I think they offer a nice introduction to the topic, and they solve this problem as Example b) in section 3.2. To sum up the argument:

0) The right space is indeed a Sobolev space, e.g. $X=\{u\in W^{1,1}(0,1): u(0)=u(1)=0\}$ where the boundary values are in the trace sense, or you could use the fact that in dimension $1$ Sobolev functions are uniformly continuous therefore you can define them pointwise.

1) You can prove that $\inf_{u\in X} I(u)=0$  using the same sequence you already used. Consider then a minimizing sequence $(u_n)$ so that $I(u_n)\to 0$. In particular the sequence $(\dot u_n)$ is bounded in $L^4$, and there is a subsequence $(\dot u_{n_k})$ which generates probability Young measures $\nu_x$. Moreover the sequence $(u_n)$ is bounded in $W^{1,4}$ and $u_n\to 0$ in $L^2$, therefore we can also suppose that the subsequence $\dot u_{n_k}$ converges weakly to zero (for instance $W^{1,\infty}$-weakly*).

2) Set $g(p)=\min\{(p^2-1)^2,1\}$. This is a bounded continuous function, and from the boundedness in $L^4$ of $\dot u_{n_k}$ in the limit we obtain(*)
$$\int\limits_0^1dx\int\limits_{\mathbb R}g(p)d\nu_x(p)=\lim_{k\to\infty} \int\limits_0^1 g(\dot u_{n_k}(x))dx\leq\lim_{k\to\infty} I(u_{n_k})=0.$$
Therefore  for a.e. $x\in(0,1)$ 
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb R}g(p)d\nu_x(p)=0$$
which implies that $\mathrm{supp}\,\nu_x\subset\{0,1\}$. We thus obtain $\nu_x=\lambda(x) \delta_1+(1-\lambda(x))\delta_{-1}$.

3) To show that $\lambda(x)=\frac12$ for a.e. $x$, use the limit properties of Young measures against the function $g(p)=p$, and obtain(*)
$$\dot u_{n_k}{\rightharpoonup}\int\limits_{\mathbb R} p \,d\nu_x(p)=\lambda(x)-(1-\lambda(x))=2\lambda(x)-1$$
which together with the fact that $\dot u_{n_k}\rightharpoonup 0$ implies $\lambda(x)=\frac12$ for a.e. $x$.

4) Since the Young measure thus obtained from the subsequence is uniquely determined, it follows that the full sequence generates the same Young measure, i.e. $\frac12\delta_1+\frac12\delta_{-1}$.

(*) Note: you have to be careful and check that you can pass to the limit when you take the composition with the function $g$: in general you can do it only for functions in $C_0(\mathbb R)$, but if you have e.g. some bound in $L^p$, $p>1$ for the sequence which generates the Young measures, then you can take $g$ with linear growth (thus $g(p)=p$ is ok).